# How do I make an timer open another html file in html

Tags: html, file, timer

So I cant find out how to open another html file from an html file after a certain amount of seconds!
My File name is homepagewebsite.html but I want it to open menu.html

PLEASE HELP!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JavaScript like following:

Like: **homepagewebsite.html**

```
<body onload=startTimer();>
<script>
function startTimer(){
var tt = setInterval(function() {
    window.open ('menu.html','_self',false)
},5000);
}
</script>
```

**menu.html**

```
<html>
<body>
   New page
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked but how do I change the time of it?

Comment: change 5000 to whatever you want. `},5000);` here.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  var iframe = window.getElementsByTagName( "iframe" )[ 0 ];
  alert( "Frame title: " + iframe.contentWindow.title );
</script>


<iframe src="page.html" width="300" height="300">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

**Open link inside iframe in another tab**

```
<base target="_blank" />
<iframe width="400" height="215" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"
   src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=es-419&amp;geocode=&amp;q=buenos+aires&amp;sll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;sspn=38.638819,80.859375&amp;t=h&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Buenos+Aires,+Argentina&amp;z=11&amp;ll=-34.603723,-58.381593&amp;output=embed">
</iframe><br />
<small>
    <a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=es-419&amp;geocode=&amp;q=buenos+aires&amp;sll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;sspn=38.638819,80.859375&amp;t=h&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Buenos+Aires,+Argentina&amp;z=11&amp;ll=-34.603723,-58.381593"
       style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">
        See bigger map
    </a>
</small>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check SmoothState.js is liabrary you can open your html pages without refresh the page and if you are perfect in jQuery then you add timer on click event, when your click is register to DOM then DOM waits for few seconds then smoothState.js open next HTML page.

http://weblinc.github.io/jquery.smoothState.js/